# Cron fails because update folder does not exist

Tags: magento2, cron, installation, crontab

I am trying to setup cron for a magento 2 installation made through composer.

I have tried to manually add the following to my crontab:

```
* * * * * www-data php /path/to/m2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /path/to/m2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * www-data php /path/to/m2/update/cron.php >> /path/to/m2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * www-data php /path/to/m2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /path/to/m2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

If I then check the `/path/to/m2/var/log/update.cron.log` I can see the following message:

> Could not open input file: /path/to/m2/update/cron.php

Obviously, because the folder `/path/to/m2/update` does not exist.

I am not sure why the folder and `cron.php` file is missing. Is there some `bin/magento` command that I have missed?

Comment: can check a file and folder permission of /update directory

Comment: @Camit1dk there is no update directory like I explained in my question?

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove the line from cron as will only make extra unused logs.**

The update/cron.php file exists in Composer- and archive-based Magento installations. It does not exist if you installed Magento by cloning the Magento 2 git repository.

In Composer-based installations, Magento creates the update/ directory when you run composer create-project. Running composer install does not create the update/ directory (if it did not exist before). See Recreate the Magento updater.

[Magento devdocs about Configure and run cron](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

**Magento version 2.3.4**, things change and the cron install generates the following cron command:

```
bin/magento cron:install --non-optional
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```